# Need assistance editing my Grub startup screen

Tags: dual-boot

Briefly; I had my windows 8 on the startup grub menu.
I'm not sure how I lost windows 8 option it's no longer
on the startup grub screen. I need to edit my grub menu to restore my
Windows 8 option.

Please assist,

Thanks

Huston

Comment: Try using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Tried boot repair with no success.